# Listen to external event in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a clojure function that reads a text file line by line, this file is being populated by an external Python script. Every now and then it will be recreated and repopulated from line 0.

I tried creating an executable jar file for my Clojure function but it gives me a Nullpointer exception which I cannot resolve. So I am running the clojure function in `lein repl` instead and leave it running in parallel as the python script.

I tried to include a [`clojure-watch`](https://github.com/derekchiang/Clojure-Watch) function to monitor if the file gets recreated but it doesn't seem to call the callback while I'm in the while loop.

My clojure function

```
(defn test [n]
  (def stop-watch (start-watch 
                [{ :path "/home/project/"
                  :event-types [:create :modify]
                  :callback (fn [event filename]
                    (when (and (.contains filename "data.txt") (= event :create))
                     (def cycle 0))
                  }]))

  (while (< cycle n)
   (let [data (read-data cycle)
         data (process-data data)]
   (def cycle (inc cycle))
))


(defn read-data [cycle]
 (loop []
  (let [
      path "/home/project/data.txt"
      Example (when (.exists (clojure.java.io/file path))
       (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader path)]
       (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr))))
      data (map clojure.edn/read-string Example)]
      (if (> (count data) cycle)
        (nth data cycle)
        (do
          (Thread/sleep 2)
          (recur)))))
)
```

How can  my clojure function know that it should reset the cycle count when the external data.txt file has reset? I don't want it to always return the last line but the exact line that the current cycle is running at - so if it's not there yet it should wait until it is there.

Any advice?

Comment: stack trace, please?

Comment: The thing that stands out the most to me is that you're using `def`s for `stop-watch` (that probably should be a `let` instead) and there's something about the logic of the `read-data` and `process-data` that I think needs to be part of the callback too: you can react to all the file modifications, but only once the file has more then 2 entries you want to produce some result.

Comment: @DenisFuenzalida but the `let` should then be before the `while` loop and inside the while loop i have another let? the problem with reacting to the file modifications using the stop-watch (`:modify`) is that it sends out two signals for one modification (I'm not sure how consistent it is), which messes up my cycle count

Answer (score 1):

I gave this a quick try and hope it will help you a bit: this simple example puts the reference to the function returned by `start-watch` into an atom so that you can keep a reference to it and use it elsewhere, so we can call it from a `(stop-monitor)` function interactively. I ran this both on the REPL in emacs with CIDER and seems to work as expected. I keep a few lines commented with `;;` so that I can evaluate them from the editor.

The demo function expects a small file (so that it can be read whole in memory with `slurp` and expects a hash-map per line with an `:amount` key and will sum them all. There's also a counter that you can use for some logic (I'm only using it for display). The idea is that you will be reacting to events, and not doing busy waiting (eg. `Thread/sleep`) waiting for the file to be created/updated.

```clj
(ns watchtest.core
  (:require [clojure-watch.core :refer [start-watch]]))

(def counter (atom 0))
(def watch-stopper (atom (fn [] (println "Not started yet!"))))

(defn process-file [event filename]
  (println "Processing" filename "after a" event "event.")
  (println "This is event #" (swap! counter inc))
  (->> (slurp filename)
       (clojure.string/split-lines)
       (map read-string)
       (map :amount) ;; assume it's a series of maps with a :amount column
       (reduce +)
       (println "Total amount:")))

(defn start-monitor []
  (let [watch-props {:path "/tmp/watchtest/files"
                     :event-types [:create :modify]
                     :bootstrap (fn [path] (println "Starting to watch" path))
                     :callback process-file
                     :options {:recursive true}}
        stop-fn (start-watch [watch-props])]
    (reset! watch-stopper stop-fn)))

(defn stop-monitor []
  (println "Stopping monitor")
  (@watch-stopper))

;; (start-monitor)
;; (stop-monitor)

(defn -main [& args]
  (start-monitor))

(defn create-demo-file []
  (let [contents (->> (range 10 20)
                      (map #(hash-map :amount %))
                      (map str)
                      (interpose "\n")
                      (reduce str))]
    (spit "/tmp/watchtest/files/demo.txt" contents)))

;; (create-demo-file)
```

Here's a sample interative session from `lein repl` as reference:

```
$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 43105 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:43105
REPL-y 0.4.3, nREPL 0.6.0
Clojure 1.10.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

watchtest.core=> (create-demo-file)
nil
watchtest.core=> (start-monitor)
Starting to watch /tmp/watchtest/files
#object[clojure_watch.core$start_watch$close_watcher__209 0x2ecd9518 "clojure_watch.core$start_watch$close_watcher__209@2ecd9518"]
watchtest.core=> (create-demo-file)
nil
Processing /tmp/watchtest/files/demo.txt after a :modify event.
This is event # 1
Total amount: 145
watchtest.core=> (create-demo-file)
nilProcessing /tmp/watchtest/files/demo.txt after a :modify event.
This is event # 2
Total amount: 145
watchtest.core=> (stop-monitor)
Stopping monitor
nil
watchtest.core=> (create-demo-file)
nil
watchtest.core=> Bye for now!
```